# Redux Action Unit Testing (Mocha & Chai)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I need help with writing unit tests for below Redux actions.
In Google, I saw some examples but the way they wrote their actions seem to be quite different so I am facing some difficulties writing unit tests for my Redux actions.

Below is the Redux actions that I have:

```js
import * as types from './readerTypes';

export const documentSuccessAction = (data) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'GET_METADATA_SUCCESS',
      metadata: data.document
    });

    dispatch({
      type: 'GET_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS',
      document : data.documentContent
    });
  };
};

export const getDocument = (docID) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => dispatch({
    type: 'API_REQUEST',
    options: {
      method: 'GET',
      service: 'reader',
      endpoint: `document/${docID}`,
      actionTypes: {
        loading: 'GET_DOCUMENT_LOADING',
        success: documentSuccessAction,
        error: 'GET_DOCUMENT_ERROR'
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: What type of difficulties are you having? What have you tried and what's not working, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you are using `redux-thunk` library, so you can find some helpful documentation about testing thunks here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md#async-action-creators

I got used that examples and It worked for me.